# How to write a unit test for method that creates an object inside of it and passes it to mocked object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Here is the method I want to test with `certificateRepository` seeing a mock and `QueryFiltersConfig config` being the object that I pass to that mock's method. I am using JUnit 5 as test framework.

```java
@Override
public List<GiftCertificateDto> fetchCertificatesWithFilters(Optional<String> tagName, Optional<List<String>> sortTypes, Optional<String> searchPattern) {
        QueryFiltersConfig.Builder filterConfigBuilder = QueryFiltersConfig.builder();
        tagName.ifPresent(filterConfigBuilder::withTag);
        addSortsToConfig(sortTypes, filterConfigBuilder);
        searchPattern.ifPresent(filterConfigBuilder::withSearchPattern);
        QueryFiltersConfig config = filterConfigBuilder.build();
        return certificateRepository.findWithFilters(config).stream()
                .map(dtoTranslator::giftCertificateToDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

How can I write the mock initialization (`Mockito.when(...)` statements) in that case? Or maybe I should do it the other way around? If so – how?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "mock initialization"? Normally you just say `var mockCr = mock(CertificateRepository.class)` and `new GiftCertificateService(mockCr)`.

Comment: I am referring to writing `Mockito.when(...)` statements

Comment: How is your `certificateRepository` field set up? Do you inject it with any DI framework?

Comment: No, I use `@InjectMocks` annotation

Comment: Do you want to test if you are passing the correct `config` object to the `certificateRepository.findWithFilters()` method? If so you can use `ArgumentCaptor`.

Comment: @Felipe answer did the job. But I found a more appropriate way in my case. Since I wasn't testing the logic connected with `QueryFiltersConfig` I used `Mockito.any()` on `findWithFilters()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ArgumentCaptor` that allows you to capture an argument passed to a method in order to inspect it. This is especially useful when you can't access the argument outside of the method we'd like to test. [Here is a good reference](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor).

Let me try to give an example based on your method. I am assuming you have a service called `YourService` which you can use `@InjectMocks` annotation to inject the mocked `CertificateRepository`.

1. Then you use the `@Captor` ArgumentCaptor field of type `QueryFiltersConfig` to store our captured argument.
2. `Mockito.verify` with the ArgumentCaptor to capture the `QueryFiltersConfig` and capture the argument using `configCaptor.getValue()`
3. Inspect the Captured Value using an assert.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CertificateRepositoryTest {
    @Mock
    CertificateRepository certificateRepository;
    @InjectMocks
    YourService yourService;
    // 1
    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<QueryFiltersConfig> configCaptor;

    @Test
    public void testWithCaptor() {
        // 2 - call your service and let it do whatever it needs
        // with the parameter passed to it
        yourService.fetchCertificatesWithFilters(parameters);

        // 2 - capture the object created inside your service
        Mockito.verify(certificateRepository)
              .findWithFilters(configCaptor.capture());
        QueryFiltersConfig value = configCaptor.getValue();
        // 3 - and make sure that the value is correct
        assertEquals(expectedValue, value);
    }
}
```